# Trigger Spring integration from a Spring batch job

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I'm looking for a way to trigger a spring integration that does file download from a spring batch job. Currently I've seen examples of triggering batch job after the integration has received the files.

Basically a step of my batch job should be fetch file from a remote server using spring integration and the next step is process it / upload to some server.

Comment: `Basically a step of my batch job should be fetch file from a remote server using spring integration and the next step is process it / upload to some server.` : Do you really need Spring Integration to download/upload a file from/to a server? I see your requirement as a 3 steps job: 1) a tasklet that downloads a file from the server, 2) a chunk-oriented step to process the file and 3) a tasklet that uploads the processed file to the server. Do you agree?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yes I agree